# Where can I find real-time indicators of economic activity?

Tags: econometrics, data-request

In this paper, they are using Canadian debit card dataset. I am not sure where to get such a dataset.

http://www.cirano.qc.ca/pdf/publication/2009s-23.pdf

My broad question is what kind of indicator can I use that indicates real-time economic activity **of the people**? Something that indicates how much people are buying on an hourly basis for an example. I am willing to look at unconventional datasets or willing to scrape information from scratch.

I thought about using Amazon review timestamps for example, but I know want to when people are buying something. Specially over the United States or smaller.

Answer (score 1):

The projects developed by [Alberto Cavallo](http://www.mit.edu/~afc/) and [Roberto Rigobon](http://web.mit.edu/rigobon/www/Robertos_Web_Page/Main.html) could be a source of inspiation.

The Billion Prices Project is an academic initiative that uses prices collected from hundreds of online retailers around the world on a **daily basis** to conduct economic research. [This page](http://bpp.mit.edu/) shows their most recent research leveraging high-frequency price data, as well as the US daily inflation index (updated monthly).

Here are the [datasets](http://bpp.mit.edu/datasets/) on Online Micro Price Data, Global Retailers Data...

Comment: Can you elaborate on why do you wish a sub-daily frequency?

Comment: I don't work in the field of economics. But I have a very high resolution rainfall dataset (in temporal resolution of minutes). I wanted to do some "fun" analysis to see if people buy more when it rains outside. More time spent outdoors = more time spent shopping. Hence, I was looking for any dataset that would correlate with shopping behavior or economic activity like credit card transaction data.

Comment: In econ, aggregating your data at the day level (and merging with the Billion Prices Project data) would still be called high frequency data ;-)! Note that the correlation could be reversed, when it rains outside I stay home.

Comment: With online retailing, this trend may have reversed, right? Earlier not going out meant not shopping. Today, it might be the opposite. Thank you for the insight.